# What should I reply when someone ask about their GDPR information against a cold marketing email?

Tags: gdpr

I recently received an email says "..please send me a GDPR information about all my data you have assigned to this email.."

I collect the email address from a public domain (say GitHub) and technically I didn't store the email or name to my system. I send a cold-marketing email with a typical sales pitch about my product.

Now, what should I reply?

Also, I didn't include any privacy page or terms of use to my website. Since I didn't run any email campaign so there is no opt-out option available.

Does it violate any GDPR clause? If so then how I'll send marketing email!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GDPR is about "processing" not "storing", so your actions definitely fall under the GDPR. Also you have stored the email address and the email you sent in your "Sent" folder.

You need to reply with all the information you have associated with that email address. This will at least be the email you already sent. If you scraped the email address from GitHub then you have it in a table with (presumably) other information such as the repository where you found it, in which case send that row of the table with the associated column headers. If you really just have a list of email addresses then say so. If you merely saw the email address and then typed a fresh email then say so.

Answer (score 4):

### You are violating anti-SPAM law in many jurisdictions

> how I'll send marketing email!

You can’t - it’s illegal in the US, Europe, Australia etc. to send unsolicited marketing emails.